# converting object to array in angular 7

Tags: arrays, object, angular7

i am getting the json response as object like below

```
machineInfo:{
    machineID: 1
    machineName: "F01"
    machineStatus: null
    alternateMachine: null
    sahPerDay: 0
    sahNextWeek: 0
    machineUnderBreakdown: false
    availabilityCurrMonth: 0
    availabilityLastMonth: 0
    availabilitySecLastMonth: 0
    complianceCurrMonth: 0
    complianceLastMonth: 0
    complianceSecLastMonth: 0
    utilizationCurrMonth: 0
    utilizationLastMonth: 0
    utilizationSecLastMonth: 0
    machineDBID: 0
    utilizationTillDate1: 0
    utilizationTillDate2: 0
    complianceTillDate: 0
}
```

I need to convert it as an array of Object

```
machineInfo:[{
    machineID: 1
    machineName: "F01"
    machineStatus: null
    alternateMachine: null
    sahPerDay: 0
    sahNextWeek: 0
    machineUnderBreakdown: false
    availabilityCurrMonth: 0
    availabilityLastMonth: 0
    availabilitySecLastMonth: 0
    complianceCurrMonth: 0
    complianceLastMonth: 0
    complianceSecLastMonth: 0
    utilizationCurrMonth: 0
    utilizationLastMonth: 0
    utilizationSecLastMonth: 0
    machineDBID: 0
    utilizationTillDate1: 0
    utilizationTillDate2: 0
    complianceTillDate: 0
}]
```

Comment: `.machineInfo = [.machineInfo]`?

Answer (score 0):

declare a global empety array:

```
result: any[] = [];
```

then:

```
this.result=[machineInfo];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let machineInfo : any = {
    machineID: 1,
    machineName: "F01",
    machineStatus: null,
    alternateMachine: null,
    sahPerDay: 0,
    sahNextWeek: 0,
    machineUnderBreakdown: false,
    availabilityCurrMonth: 0,
    availabilityLastMonth: 0,
    availabilitySecLastMonth: 0,
    complianceCurrMonth: 0,
    complianceLastMonth: 0,
    complianceSecLastMonth: 0,
    utilizationCurrMonth: 0,
    utilizationLastMonth: 0,
    utilizationSecLastMonth: 0,
    machineDBID: 0,
    utilizationTillDate1: 0,
    utilizationTillDate2: 0,
    complianceTillDate: 0,
}

machineInfo = [machineInfo]

console.log(machineInfo);
```